# "Ich möchte das gerne machen" or "Ich würde das gerne machen"

Tags: meaning, usage

What is correct, between

> (a) Ich möchte das gerne machen.

and

> (b) Ich würde das gerne machen.

or both? If both are correct, is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: Beides ist Ok. Aber "würde" ist Konjunktiv und "möchte" nicht.

Comment: Isn't möchte the subjunctive 2 form of mögen?

Comment: @thekeyofgb: It can also be, but is rarely used as such, only in older literature.

Comment: ...was ist *"möchte"* denn anderes als der Konjunktiv 2 von *mögen*???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are correct but there indeed may be a difference in meaning.

Who wants to answer the question?

> Ich möchte das gerne machen. Wenn ich darf.

vs

> Ich würde das gerne machen. Ich habe aber keine Zeit.
>   Ich würde das gerne machen. Wenn ich darf.

The point is, when using *möchte* you say you're really willing to do something but you're waiting for permission.

Using *würde* can mean the same thing but it can also indicate that you would do it but you simply can't.

It's usually clear from context, however in case of "I can't" you tell why.

Comment: Also, "würde" will be used if you are not exactly keen to do it. "Ich würde es schon machen, ehe wir den Auftrag verlieren, obwohl es eigentlich nicht meine Aufgabe ist."

Comment: Ich würde es machen, wenn ich nicht zu faul wäre.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to EM1's answer:

> Ich möchte das gerne machen

can also mean that you just didn't get to do it yet, but are definitely willing to.

For example:

> Eines Tages möchte ich noch an den Nordpol.

It is your wish to go there, but so far you didn't get to do it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to EM1's answer, which is 100% correct, I think if you take the standalone sentence

> Ich würde das gerne machen.

this will be a little bit more polite – but this is a very small difference.
Also, this does not mean the other statement is impolite in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is as follows:

- Ich möchte das machen = I want to do that
- Ich würde das machen = I would like to do that