# What’s the difference between “möchte”, “will”, “lieber”, “würde”?

Tags: difference, word-choice, politeness

Each of the expressions *möchte*, *will*, *lieber*, *würde* seems to mean *I want / I wish / I’d like*.

For example:

> Was würden Sie gern essen?

Can you help me to understand the difference between them?

Comment: Perhaps you can read the link given as part of the answer to [your own question](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/637/1691) in the meta: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences  Maybe not mentioned there, but it's not too difficult to type `ü`, `ä`, and `ö`, in turn, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you give an example for each? As they are, I do not understand all of them.

Comment: maybe this also helps: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9748/ich-mochte-das-gerne-machen-or-ich-wurde-das-gerne-machen/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is very well explained [here](http://learn-german.language101.com/how-to-learn-german/when-should-i-say-mochte-wurde-or-hatte/). I hope this helps.

*Willst du* is 2nd person singular of *wollen*. It is a desire coming from your will/head rather then a hearts wish. When you order in a restaurant you often choose *möchten* (subjunctive of *mögen*) than *wollen*, because it is much more polite.

> Ich will ... = *I want ...*
>
> Ich möchte ... = *I'd like ...*

Also refer to this Q&A: ["Ich möchte das gerne machen" or "Ich würde das gerne machen"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9748/ich-mochte-das-gerne-machen-or-ich-wurde-das-gerne-machen/)