# Difference between wollen and möchten

Tags: usage

I was wondering what is difference between wollen and möchten? When exactly do we have to use each of both?

for example, which of the following is correct?

- Ich möchte Ingenieur werden.
- Ich will Ingenieur werden.

Comment: Please note that there is no infinitive _möchten_. The _möchten_-forms are (at least formally) Konjunktiv-II-forms of the infinitive _mögen_.

Comment: Does http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10939/whats-the-difference-between-m%C3%B6chte-willst-du-lieber-w%C3%BCrden/10944#10944 help you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Wollen" expresses a (perhaps very) strong will to achieve something. Using it can make an aggressive impression and so it is rarely used in formal letters, but rather at a protest march or a heated debate.

> "Wir `wollen` mehr Gerechtigkeit für Arbeitslose!"
>   "Ich `will`, dass du sofort aufhörst zu rauchen."

"Möchten" is a polite way of expressing will and is often used in formal letters. It can also be a way of avoiding to express absolute certainty of your will.

> "Ich `möchte` Sie (freundlich) bitten, mir weiteres Informationsmaterial zu senden."
>   "Er `möchte` die Qualität seines Unterrichts hoch halten."

Comment: So if I want to ask someone "What do you want", it will be "Was möchtest du?" .. right?

Comment: @fujy.. that depends on context. If you want to be polite, then yes, you'd use "möchten", if you want to be not polite or if you're with friends you'd use "wollen"